# Input data of different types from a file and NOT USING VECTORS

Tags: c++, arrays, database, input

First off I am new to C++ so dont mark me down for not knowing something or being incorrect. I have a file that I am trying to read into my C++ program. I am doing a practice for a project. I have to create and object, and where each instance represents contines one line of the file with seven variables. The file contains a database. The format of the text file is:

```
// String String Character Int Int Char Int 
// String String Character Int Int Char Int
// etc.
```

There is exactly 350 data members. There is never more. So I am using arrays.
**I can not use vectors for this project as it is specified not to.**

**What is the best way to approach this with only using arrays?**

my first attempt was to create a 3 arrays:

```
        for (int l = 0; l < max_size; l++) {
            myfile >> myintarray[l];
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < max_size; k++) {
            myfile >> mychararray[k];
        }
       for (int i = 0; i < max_size; i++) {
            myfile >> myarray[i];
            // print artists and title; 
        }

       // Then I have to put it the object. Store as such....
        myloop = 0;
        a = 2;
        b = 5;
        while (myloop < 50) {
            myartwork[myloop].setRoom(mychararray[b]);
            myartwork[myloop].myart.setMeduim(mychararray[a]);
            a += 7;
            b += 7;
            myloop += 1;
        }
       // more code where I do the same thing with characters
       // same things with strings.....
```

When I tried that it printed off the contents. it was inccorect. and mumbo jumbo. 
So I think it is because I am when I try to store the all number array it cant take characters and prints out an error? I am not sure if that is correct.

So then I tried to use only one array that was string then convert it each string into a char or int type. and that was a pain and I get an error. and I am not sure how to handdle the character type.

```
            myloop = 0;
            a = 3;
            b = 4;
            c = 6;
            while (myloop < 50) {
                //std::stoi (str_dec,&sz)
                std::string::size_type sz;

                // my object ( instance). data......Try to convert this. 
                myartwork[myloop].mymysize.setLength(std::stoi(myarray[a],  &sz));
                myartwork[myloop].mymysize.setWidth(std::stoi(myarray[b], &sz));
                myartwork[myloop].setPrice(std::stoi(myarray[c], &sz));
                a += 7;
                b += 7;
                c += 7;
                myloop += 1;
            }
```

Is there a better way to do this then these two methods? Am I on the right track?

Comment: _"I can not use vectors"_. Use `std::deque` then. Or `std::list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using many arrays with the same capacity is usually a sign of a poor design.

Let's talk modeling here.  Let's define a record as a container of fields.  The record would correspond with one text line in your file.  So, model it:

```
struct Record
{
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    char        c1;
    int         i1;
    int         i2;
    char        c1;
    int         i3;
};
```

Now you can declare a table, or an *array* of records:

```
#define MAXIMUM_RECORDS (350)
Record database[MAXIMUM_RECORDS];
```

Some more things to do:

1. Overload `operator >>` to read from input file.
2. Implement constructors, copy constructors and assignment operator.
3. Overload comparison operators: `==`, `>`, etc.
4. Overload `operator <<` to print the record.